Playwright sometimes reports false Pass in default report?

   async clickSearchReult(context: Context, testInfo:TestInfo,enteredValue: string) {
        const [newPage] = await this.newWindowNavigate(context, enteredValue);
        //this.addNotestToAccount(context,testInfo, enteredValue);
        return newPage;

    }

async addNotesToAccount(testInfo:TestInfo){
   test.step("Add Notes to Account",async ()=>{
   await this.newPage.setViewportSize({ width: 1020, height: 940 });
   await this.menusAccountDetailsPage(data.AccountDetailsPageNotesIcon).waitFor();
   await this.menusAccountDetailsPage(data.AccountDetailsPageNotesIcon).isVisible();
   await this.menusAccountDetailsPage(data.AccountDetailsPageNotesIcon).highlight();
   await this.menusAccountDetailsPage(data.AccountDetailsPageNotesIcon).click({delay:3000});
   await this.addNotesButton.waitFor();
   await this.addNotesButton.click({delay:2000});
   await this.enterNotesTextArea.fill("text for demo");
   await this.saveButton.click();
   const screenshot = await this.newPage.screenshot();
   await testInfo.attach("Adding Notes", { body: screenshot, contentType: 'image/png' });
      });
     }

Calling the above method from test.
  await home.navigateToSearchPage();
  const searchPage = new SearchPage(page);
 
  await searchPage.searchWithAdditionalQueries(testInfo, "Accounts", "Account","equals",returnvalues.account,false);
  newPageforAccount=await searchPage.clickSearchReult(context,returnvalues.account);

  const accountDetailsPage= new AccountDetailsPage(newPageforAccount);
  await accountDetailsPage.addNotesToAccount(testInfo);

On click of Hyperlink of account, account details page is opened in new window.. that new page is not normal size playwright (but when you do manually in chrome the page correctly displaying all content but in playwright it is not showing full page) .
so i am doing viewPortSize.. and clicking NotesIcon to highlight and add.. It is hightlighting correct but not adding so failing.. but report shows Passed.
Instead if I directly use locators without passing to constructor.. then it is working..
async addNotestToAccount(context:Context, testInfo:TestInfo,enteredValue:string){
    const [newPage] = await this.newWindowNavigate(context, enteredValue);
    var screenshot = await newPage.screenshot();
    await testInfo.attach("Search Results navigation", { body: screenshot, contentType: 'image/png' });
    await newPage.locator("//*[@data-mat-icon-name='"+data.AccountDetailsPageNotesIcon+"']").click();
    await newPage.locator("//*[@aria-label='confirmButton']").click();
    const notesString = await this.generateRandomString(15);
    await newPage.locator("//*[@placeholder='Add Notes...']").fill(notesString);
    await newPage.locator(this.saveButton).click({ delay: 1000 });
    await newPage.locator(this.notesTableHeader).waitFor();
}

{
"compilerOptions": {
"strictNullChecks": false
}
}
